# GET http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.mjs net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE NX micro front-end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Using NX microfront to serve the multiple application over HTTPS, getting an exception as

```
GET http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.mjs net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

In package.json

```
"serve": {
  "executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "product:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "product:build:development"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
    "port": 4201,
    "publicHost": "https://localhost:4201",
    "ssl": true,
    "sslKey": "././certificate/localhost.key",
    "sslCert": "././certificate/localhost.crt"
  }
},
```

In the development I am serving the application in HTTPS, how in the browser console

[image]

Removing the HTTPS works fine. Using the latest NX version 16.0.0